# A general incidence problem

Tags: combinatorics

In some problems there are $m$ people $p_1,\dots,p_m$ is given and it is given each person $p_i$ knows $t_i$ number of people.

If the problem is framed under some conditions it seems that one can guess the exact people that each $p_i$ knows just from the numbers $t_i$.

Is there a general framework to understand what those conditions could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is when a graph is uniquely determined by its degree sequence. Here is a paper from 1975 on this topic to get you started.

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895675900726

Comment: I just found out that these graphs are called "unigraphs" in the literature. Catchy name!

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223349/uniquely-describing-a-graph